# How to use FG ground on a meanwell buck DC\DC power supply

Tags: power-supply, voltage, power, safety

I would like to know how to safely connect a 48V 200A battery to a step-down converter. The step-down converter is [this](https://mantech.co.za/Datasheets/Products/SD-100-MW.pdf). SO the step-down converter is to be used inside a forklift to drop the 48V DC to 24V DC.

The block diagram for this power supply is:
[image]

The mechanical specs are:
[image]

I know that the positive (red wire) from the battery of goes to V+ of the power supply and the negative (black wire) from the battery goes to V- of the power supply.

However, how do I connect the FG (floating ground) pin (pin 3)? Does this get screwed into the metal frame of the forklift?

[Manual](https://www.meanwell.com/Upload/PDF/DC-DC_EN.pdf)

Comment: There must be a manual for this because the information in that data sheet is a little crappy. It doesn't even mention what internal fire-protection fuse it has.

Comment: @Andyaka cannot find any other info besides that datasheet in the post from the manufacturer.

Comment: Sorry can't help you on that but, what about contacting them?

Comment: MeanWell usually has the mounting instructions as separate download, as same instructions are valid for multiple models. And the datasheet is for multiple models as well. Go to manufacturer website directly, sellers don't provide these instructions. FG also means Frame Ground.

Comment: @Justme they say FG must be connected to earth ground. But how do you do this with a DC battery?

Comment: @Andyaka managed to find a manual. see post update

Comment: @Joey yes well you woudn't since it is a vehicle. But you are going to bolt it on the vehicle chassis, right?

Comment: @Joey For a vehicle, usually the metal frame of the vehicle is treated as ground. But don't quote me on that.

Comment: @Justme Honestly I do not know how this works. This is the first I come across a separate ground terminal for a DC to DC converter. So what is the point of grounding the power supply to the frame of the forklift?

Comment: @Joey if the FG has a connection to the power supply metal case, and you are mounting the power supply from the metal case to forklift metal chassis so that there is good connection, you should be done. Otherwise connect a wire from FG to forklift metal chassis.

Comment: @Justme so basically I first check if there is continuity between the metal case and the FG terminal. If there is this means I can "mount the power supply from the metal case to forklift metal chassis so that there is a good connection, you should be done." Otherwise, I need to connect the FG to the metal chassis. In addition, I need to verify that the negative terminal (pin 2) of the power supply also has continuity with the FG terminal. If not then I also need to connect a wire that bridges pin 2 (battery negative terminal) to pin 3 (FG terminal). Is this a correct understanding?

Comment: @Joey I did not assume you were going to use the chassis as negative supply return path. Using the chassis as return path might work. I assumed you were connecting the battery with two wires to power supply. Even if the power supply metal frame is connected to FG pin, the FG pin is not meant to carry supply current, so only connecting a link between pins 2&3 might damage the supply. I don't recommend using power supply case and internal connections as return path.

Comment: @Justme okay so I got the idea from the vehicle negative terminal of the battery been connected to the metal body of the vehicle. Hence I thought of bridging the pin 2 and 3 together. But according to what you are saying the FG pin must not be used like that for this application. I should only connect that pin to the chassis of the forklift or connect the metal cage to the body if the FG pin is connected to the cage. So what's the point of the FG pin in the power supply, what is its function and what will happen if it's not connected?

Comment: @Joey if you are using the vehicle chassis as return path, simply connect it to pin 2 (negative input) as that is where the large currents flow. FG pin is for setting the power supply case potential and for better suppression of common mode electromagnetic interference (EMI), as the FG pin has so called Y capacitors to both input negative terminal and output negative terminal. You will experience higher EMI if the FG pin or supply case are left unconnected (I assume FG is internally connected to supply metal case here). So FG or metal case should to be connected to vehicle chassis too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116923/discussion-between-joey-and-justme).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FG pin is to ground the emi filter to a low impedance ground, in the manual this would be earth. Since that isn't possible on a forklift (because you'd probably want to move it) then connect it to the chassis. By connecting it to the chassis EMI from the cables or supply can return back to the supply through the FG pin instead of radiate.

Comment: How do I determine the awg of the wire that connects from the chassis to the FG pin?

Comment: I would probably keep the cable as thick as possible and short as possible to minimize inductance, at least 24AWG. 1ft of 24AWG would be 20mΩ that won't be noticed by anything.